# Can´t use survfit on some data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, survival-analysis

I have a dataset I´m going to use for survival analysis, and it seems to be working fine when I use the whole set. However, once I slice it into smaller dataframes using `data[which(data$variable1=="somevalue")]`the thing seems to break down.

Most of the resulting smaller dataframes work fine, but some are a problem. In the problematic ones, I can use `summary(survfit(Surv(time, status)~variable2, data=smalldataframe))$surv` without a problem, but when I try `summary(survfit(Surv(time, status)~variable2, data=smalldataframe), time=5)$surv`, it throws `Error in array(xx, dim = dd) : negative length vectors are not allowed`.

I´ve tried looking at the data, to see if I have any weird values, like negative times, but there aren´t any. Besides, if there were a problem with that, the full dataframe should be throwing an error too, but it doesn´t. All the smaller dataframes are created using the same line of code, so I also don´t understand why they are acting differently. And mostly, I don´t understand why `summary(survfit(...))$surv` works fine, as does `plot(survfit(...))`, but when I want to calculate survival at a specific time, it suddenly doesn´t like the data anymore.

Here´s one of the offending dataframes

```
test <-
structure(list(time2 = c(0.15, 2.08, 2.06, 0.32, 39.45, 39.09, 
2.57, 3.64, 13.57, 36.57, 36.26, 0.78, 0.1, 33.94, 3.1, NA, 1.77, 
28.38, 1.24, NA, 1.87, 25.83, 2.62, 1.57, 1.6, 22.74, 21.03, 
20.54, 20.03, 0.97, 19.35, 18.09, 2.61, 17.68, NA, 3.85, 3.52, 
11.22, 11.52, 11.04, 10.51, 1.68, 10.4, 10.61, 9.01, 9.05, 7.8, 
0.11, 4.83), status = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, NA, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), cas_dg = c(1, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)), .Names = c("time2", "status", "cas_dg"), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = "data.frame")
```

The call that is giving me trouble is `summary(survfit(Surv(time2, status)~cas_dg, data=test), time=5)$surv` and that only with some of the smaller dataframes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use argument `extend=TRUE` in `summary`; according to `?summary.survfit`:

> extend: logical value: if TRUE, prints information for all specified
>             ‘times’, even if there are no subjects left at the end of the
>             specified ‘times’.  This is only valid if the ‘times’
>             argument is present.

So for your sample data, you can do:

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(time2, status) ~ cas_dg, data = test);
summary(fit, time = 5, extend = TRUE)$surv;
#[1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5555556 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.5714286 0.6000000
#[8] 0.6666667 0.8000000
```